# What is the R function for detecting successive differences in a data frame?

Tags: r

I use the following code in R and it works very well. More precisely, I compare each time *cluster_id* with the last *cluster_ref* to see when they differ 2 periods in a row (data is organized by fund_numbers). However, I would like to adapt it to 5 periods. But it is impossible to make it work. Do you have any idea how I can modify this code to solve my problem?

```
get_output <- function(mon, ref){

  exp <- !is.na(Cluster_id) & !map2_lgl(Cluster_id, last(Cluster_ref), identical)

  as.integer(exp & lag(exp, default = FALSE))

}


df %>%

  arrange(Fund_number, rolling_window) %>% 

  group_by(Fund_number) %>% 

  mutate(Deviation = get_output(Cluster_id, Cluster_ref)) %>% 

  ungroup()
```

```
rolling_window   Fund_number   Cluster_id   Cluster_ref   Expected_output
1                1             10           10            0
2                1             10           10            0
3                1             8            9             0
4                1             8            8             0
5                1             7            7             0
6                1             8            8             0
7                1             8            NA            1
8                1             7            NA            1
9                1             7            10            1
10               1             10           10            0
1                2             NA           NA            0
2                2             NA           3             0
3                2             3            3             0
4                2             2            5             0
5                2             2            NA            0
6                2             2            4             0
7                2             2            4             1
8                2             5            5             0
9                2             4            5             0
10               2             3            5             0
```

This is what I want.
So as you can see, the data is organized by fund_number. Then I look at the last cluster_ref for each fund (so every 8 rows) and compare it to each cluster_id for each fund. As soon as it is different at least 5 periods in a row I have 1 if not 0. So for each fund, I compare the 8th cluster_ref and the cluster_id of rows 1 to 8.

The code above makes this but with 2 time periods.

Thank you very much,

Vanie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data.table` we can use `rleid` over `Cluster_id` values.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, temp := rleid(last(Cluster_ref) != Cluster_id), Fund_number]
df[, output := +(seq_along(Cluster_ref) >= 5), .(Fund_number, temp)]
df[, temp := NULL]
df
#    rolling_window Fund_number Cluster_id Cluster_ref Expected_output output
# 1:              1           1         10          10               0      0
# 2:              2           1         10          10               0      0
# 3:              3           1          8           9               0      0
# 4:              4           1          8           8               0      0
# 5:              5           1          7           7               0      0
# 6:              6           1          8           8               0      0
# 7:              7           1          8          NA               1      1
# 8:              8           1          7          NA               1      1
# 9:              9           1          7          10               1      1
#10:             10           1         10          10               0      0
#11:              1           2         NA          NA               0      0
#12:              2           2         NA           3               0      0
#13:              3           2          3           3               0      0
#14:              4           2          2           5               0      0
#15:              5           2          2          NA               0      0
#16:              6           2          2           4               0      0
#17:              7           2          2           4               1      1
#18:              8           2          5           5               0      0
#19:              9           2          4           5               0      0
#20:             10           2          3           5               0      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ronak Shah but I don't get the result I expected in my real file (I edited the reproducible example). 
In fact, more precisely, I would like for each fund_number, to compare the last line of cluster_ref (so every 10 observations here) with all the lines of cluster i_d (line 1 to 10) and start again at each new fund_number. If cluster_id = cluster_ref then I have 0 because no deviation/difference. As soon as the deviation reaches 5 in a row, I have 1 until cluster_id=cluster_ref again (for NA value, it is considered neither different nor equal). How can I change the code?

Comment: @GauthierGolin I see. I have updated the answer, can you take a look?

Comment: I get the expected output! So thank you for your help @RonakShah !